Optimistic Concurrency Exception when Updating Entity with List<saleComments> Relationship in Entity Framework Core
I am trying to update a saleOrder entity in the database using Entity Framework Core. The entity has a property List<saleComments> Comments.
I have an issue when attempting to save the changes, where I get an optimistic concurrency exception:

Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Here is the code I am using:
public void SaveSaleOrder(saleOrder saleOrder)
{
    try
    {
        _log.WriteToLog($"Attempting to find SaleOrder with PEC_NUM_PEDIDO = {saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO}");

        var existingSaleOrder = _context.SaleOrders
            .Include(s => s.Comments)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO == saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO);

        if (existingSaleOrder == null)
        {
            if (saleOrder != null)
            {
                var result = SaveOrUpdatePayment(saleOrder.PaymentStatus);
                saleOrder.PECPG_SEQUENCIA = result;
            }

            _context.SaleOrders.Add(saleOrder);
            _log.WriteToLog("ORDER CREATED.");
        }
        else
        {
            var existingEntry = _context.Entry(existingSaleOrder);
            var saleOrderEntry = _context.Entry(saleOrder);

            foreach (var property in saleOrderEntry.Properties)
            {
                // Ignore the primary key
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                    continue;               

                // Update the property value
                existingEntry.Property(property.Metadata.Name).CurrentValue = property.CurrentValue;
            }

            // Update comments
            UpdateComments(existingSaleOrder.Comments, saleOrder.Comments);

            _log.WriteToLog("ORDER UPDATED.");
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.WriteToLog("Error saving to the database: " + ex.Message);
        ProcessConfig.Error += 1;
        throw;
    }
}

private void UpdateComments(ICollection<saleComments> existingComments, ICollection<saleComments> newComments)
{
    // Remove existing comments
    foreach (var existingComment in existingComments.ToList())
    {
        _context.Comments.Remove(existingComment);
    }

    // Add new comments
    foreach (var newComment in newComments)
    {
        existingComments.Add(newComment);
    }
}

private int SaveOrUpdatePayment(salePayment payment)
{
    var existingPayment = _context.SalePayments
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Payment_Method == payment.Payment_Method &&
                             p.Payment_Description == payment.Payment_Description);

    if (existingPayment == null)
    {
        _context.SalePayments.Add(payment);
        _log.WriteToLog("PAYMENT CREATED.");
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return payment.PECPG_SEQUENCIA;
    }
    else
    {
        existingPayment.Payment_Description = payment.Payment_Description;
        existingPayment.Payment_Method = payment.Payment_Method;
        _context.SalePayments.Update(existingPayment);
        _log.WriteToLog("PAYMENT UPDATED.");
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return existingPayment.PECPG_SEQUENCIA;
    }
}

Problem Details
I get the optimistic concurrency exception when trying to save changes to the database:

Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)
Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I am trying to update an existing saleOrder, including its scalar properties and the list of saleComments.
I am using _context.SaleOrders.Include(s => s.Comments) to load the comments associated with the saleOrder.
The scalar properties are working but I couldn't get the comments updated.
Question
What could be causing this concurrency exception and how can I resolve it?
Is there a more efficient or correct way to update an entity with a List<saleComments> relationship without encountering concurrency issues?
Edit 01
Using the following code i got this error: Error saving to the database: The property 'PEC_SEQUENCIA' on entity type 'SaleOrder' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.
   public void SaveSaleOrder(SaleOrder saleOrder)
   {
       if (saleOrder == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(saleOrder));

       try
       {
           _log.WriteToLog($"Attempting to find SaleOrder with PEC_NUM_PEDIDO = {saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO}");

           var existingSaleOrder = _context.SaleOrders
               .Include(s => s.Comments)
               .FirstOrDefault(s => s.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO == saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO);

           if (existingSaleOrder == null)
           {
               var result = SaveOrUpdatePayment(saleOrder.PaymentStatus);
               saleOrder.PECPG_SEQUENCIA = result;
               _context.SaleOrders.Add(saleOrder);
               _log.WriteToLog("ORDER CREATED.");
           }
           else
           {
               _context.Entry(existingSaleOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(saleOrder);
               UpdateComments(existingSaleOrder, saleOrder);
               _log.WriteToLog("ORDER UPDATED.");
           }

           _context.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           _log.WriteToLog("Error saving to the database: " + ex.Message);
           ProcessConfig.Error += 1;
           throw;
       }
   }
   private void UpdateComments(SaleOrder existingSaleOrder, SaleOrder newSaleOrder)
   {
       var existingCommentIds = existingSaleOrder.Comments.Select(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA).ToList();

       var newCommentIds = newSaleOrder.Comments.Select(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA).ToList();

       var commentIdsToAdd = newCommentIds.Except(existingCommentIds);
       var commentIdsToRemove = existingCommentIds.Except(existingCommentIds);
       var commentIdsToUpdate = newCommentIds.Intersect(existingCommentIds);

       foreach (var id in commentIdsToRemove)
       {
           var comment = existingSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA == id);
           existingSaleOrder.Comments.Remove(comment);
       }
       foreach (var id in commentIdsToUpdate)
       {
           SaleComments existingComment = existingSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA == id);
           SaleComments updatedComment = newSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA == id);
           existingComment.comment_Date = updatedComment.comment_Date;
           existingComment.comment_Data = updatedComment.comment_Data;
           existingComment.comment_Status = updatedComment.comment_Status;
       }
       foreach (var id in commentIdsToAdd)
       {
           var comment = newSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.PECHC_SEQUENCIA == id);
           existingSaleOrder.Comments.Add(comment);
       }
   }

   private int SaveOrUpdatePayment(SalePayment payment)
   {
       var existingPayment = _context.SalePayments
           .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Payment_Method == payment.Payment_Method &&
                                p.Payment_Description == payment.Payment_Description);

       if (existingPayment == null)
       {
           _context.SalePayments.Add(payment);

           _log.WriteToLog("PAGAMENTO CRIADO.");

           _context.SaveChanges();
           return payment.PECPG_SEQUENCIA;
       }
       else
       {
           existingPayment.Payment_Description = payment.Payment_Description;
           existingPayment.Payment_Method = payment.Payment_Method;

           _context.SalePayments.Update(existingPayment);

           _log.WriteToLog("PAGAMENTO ATUALIZADO.");

            _context.SaveChanges();
           return existingPayment.PECPG_SEQUENCIA;
       }
   }


learn.microsoft.com/resolving-concurrency-conflicts

The issue will likely be around how you are trying to update the comments, plus there are a few steps you are doing that are unnecessary that may also be tripping up EF. Also, when working with the DBContext it is important to treat it like a unit of work, ideally there should be one, and only one call to SaveChanges for a given operation. So supporting methods like the payment processing method called by the main operation should avoid calling SaveChanges.
Starting with The SaveOrder method:
public void SaveSaleOrder(saleOrder saleOrder)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(nameof(saleOrder));
    try
    {
        _log.WriteToLog($"Attempting to find SaleOrder with PEC_NUM_PEDIDO = {saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO}");

        var existingSaleOrder = _context.SaleOrders
            .Include(s => s.Comments)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO == saleOrder.PEC_NUM_PEDIDO);

        if (existingSaleOrder == null)
        {
            var result = SaveOrUpdatePayment(saleOrder.PaymentStatus);
            saleOrder.PECPG_SEQUENCIA = result;
            _context.SaleOrders.Add(saleOrder);
            _log.WriteToLog("ORDER CREATED.");
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Entry(existingSaleOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(saleOrder);
            UpdateComments(existingSaleOrder, saleOrder);
            _log.WriteToLog("ORDER UPDATED.");
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.WriteToLog("Error saving to the database: " + ex.Message);
        ProcessConfig.Error += 1;
        throw;
    }
}

Most of what you have is good. Assert the SaleOrder not null check at the start, the method should never be called without one, so this avoids nesting null checks as your code would still end up having raised a NullReferenceException when you tried logging with the sale order properties. For updating the properties, EF provides a SetValues() method. A better approach IMO is to either copy values explicitly or use a configured mapper. Often when updating data you will only expect certain values to change so being explicit ensures that readers of your code understand what is expected to change and only those specified values can change. (lessens risk of bugs or tampering) For the UpdateComments we will pass the two sale order references rather than their comments collections. This is just to make it clear we are modifying the entities so future developers don't do something like filter the collection passed in which would break the behaviour.
Next UpdateComments. When adding and removing associated entities, avoid the temptation of dumping the existing items and re-adding them from the updated source. When you remove an item from a tracked collection EF notes that an item should be removed, but if you add the same item again that can trip things up.
The below example assumes that comments are entity references that are owned by sales orders rather than references, meaning you add and remove new comments in a one-to-many relationship rather than associate a sale order to an existing comments in a many-to-many relationship. This assumes that for new comments you are defining an ID for the comment client side. If new comments have an unset ID then the below logic would be done a little different, just check for the default 0 or null PK on the newComments for inserts.
private void UpdateComments(SaleOrder existingSaleOrder, SaleOrder newSaleOrder)
{
    var existingCommentIds = existingSaleOrder.Comments.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var newCommentIds = newSaleOrder.Comments.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    var commentIdsToAdd = newCommentIds.Except(existingCommentIds);
    var commentIdsToRemove = existingCommentIds.Except(existingCommentIds);
    var commentIdsToUpdate = newCommentIds.Intersect(existingCommentIds);

    foreach(var id in commentIdsToRemove)
    {
        var comment = existingSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.Id == id);
        existingSaleOrder.Comments.Remove(comment);
    }
    foreach(var id in commentIdsToUpdate)
    {
        var existingComment = existingSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.Id == id);
        var updatedComment = newSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.Id == id);
        existingComment.CommentText = updatedComment.CommentText; // Example field, adjust to suit
        // .. Any other properties that can be updated...
    }
    foreach(var id in commentIdsToAdd)
    {
        var comment = newSaleOrder.Comments.First(x => x.Id == id);
        existingSaleOrder.Comments.Add(comment);
    }
}

So the crux of the updated method is to compare the IDs to find what entries have been added, removed, or potentially updated. We start by removing any items that should no longer be there, then going through the update list before adding any comments that should be added. The reason for this order is just to reduce the collection before expanding it to minimize time finding items. The nice thing about EF change tracking is that in the case of updates, it will only actually generate an UPDATE SQL statement if the value actually changes, so you don't need to add the overhead of checking if the values actually changed or not. EF already takes care of that.
For the UpdatePayment method, this should pretty much be OK, just remove the calls to SaveChanges.
This should hopefully help resolve your concurrency issue.

Thank @Steve Py for the detailed response. I encountered these challenges:
_ Save Payment First: Payment must be saved before the order as PECPG_SEQUENCIA depends on it.
_ SetValues PK Error: Using SetValues causes a primary key error.
_ Controlled Key: XXX_SEQUENCIA must not be modified. All XXX_SEQUENCIA keys are controlled by me and set in MapSales using context.XXX.Count() + 1, ensuring uniqueness before came in Save method
How can I adjust the code to save the payment first and avoid PK issues with SetValues?

On line var commentIdsToRemove = existingCommentIds.Except(existingCommentIds); the return isn't null?

You shouldn't need to "save the payment first". EF Core will handle saving primary entities before dependent entities when you call save with your changes.

You are right, about the other issue, you know how solve it?

In that case you can have the Payment call SaveChanges. Multiple calls are not illegal, just something that should be avoided wherever possible but there may be the odd case that they are needed.  However, what you describe for that XXX_Sequencia sounds very inefficient and error prone. PK/FK should be meaningless values representing just the relationship between two rows. The PK of a row should not reflect something like a count of related records requiring records to be deleted and recreated if something like a count changes. Counts are also point in time dependent. (multi-user?)

I know, but here where i work the DB works in that way. Anyway, i fixed my problem using an new instance of the object Comment and using SaveChances twice, one for the sale and other for the Comments
